# Parametric polymorphism in c#?

Tags: c#, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to create a parametric polmorphism function in c#:

I want to have `T` be the type variable. But I am getting error about class `T` is not found.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
    public List<T> getX(SPListItemCollection itemCollection, List<T> itemList, Report RO, WebpartSettings WPS)
    {
        foreach (T item in itemCollection)
        {
            if (have_permissions_for_item(WPS.EDIT_MODE, item, RO))
            {
                itemList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return itemList;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
public List<T> getX(SPListItemCollection itemCollection, List<T> itemList, Report RO, WebpartSettings WPS)
```

to

```
public List<T> getX<T>(SPListItemCollection itemCollection, List<T> itemList, Report RO, WebpartSettings WPS)
```

Have a closer look at how [Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does it.